# Which XML parser can handle an incomplete XML file?

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an XML using SAX Parser but keep getting `XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.` which is expected as the XML doc I get from other source won't be a proper one. But I don't want this exception to be raised as I would like to parse an XML document till I find the `<myTag>` in that document and I don't care whether that doc got proper starting and closing entities.

Example:

```
<employeeDetails>
  <firstName>xyz</firsName>
  <lastName>orp</lastName>
  <departmentDetails>
  <departName>SALES</departName>
  <departCode>982</departCode>...
```

Here I don't want to care whether the document is valid one or not as this part is not in my hand. So I would like to parse this document till I see `<departName>` after that I don't want to parse the document. Please suggest me how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an XML parser to parse a file that does not contain well-formed XML.  (It does not have to be *valid*, just *well-formed*.  For the difference, read [**Well-formed vs Valid XML**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).)

**By definition, XML must be well-formed, otherwise *it is not XML***.  Parsers in general have to have some fundamental constraints met in order to operate, and for XML parsers, it is well-formedness.

Either repair the file manually first to be well-formed XML, or open it programmatically and ***parse it as a text*** file using traditional parsing techniques.  **An XML parser cannot help you unless you have well-formed XML.**

### See also

- [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Good to know that we can't parse incomplete XML using parser. I will try to do it in traditional parsing way as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) in Python can handle incomplete xml really well.
I use it to parse prefix of large XML files for preview.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup('<a><b>foo</b><b>bar<','xml')
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="unicode-escape"?>\n<a><b>foo</b><b>bar</b></a>
```